# Where is the source of the VNC server in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

Can you please tell me where can I find the source for the VNC server for  Ubuntu?

Comment: Which VNC server are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
apt-get source vnc-server
```

This will download the source for the vnc-server package into the current directory.

#### Update for Hardy:

```
apt-get source tightvncserver
```

or

```
apt-get source vnc4server
```

Just depends on which server you prefer to use.

Comment: +1 but it looks like the OP is using Hardy Heron from his posting history so there is no package `vnc-server`. The package list for Hardy is at http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/x11/

Comment: Ah, the posting history: to help the tight-lipped, finally a convenient alternative to mind reading.